# What's the name of this timeline package in LaTeX?

Tags: packages, diagrams, pgfgantt

I tried searching through many resources to identify the package that allows to create this type of time lines:

[image: Timeline]

but all in vain. Could anyone, please, point in the right direction?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from another stackexchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question. Please make sure that all images are uploaded using the official stackexchange interface, i.e. the image icon on top of the text field (shortcut: CTRL+G). This ensures that all images are always accessible and do not expire.

Comment: As new user without image posting privileges simply include the image as normal and remove the `!` in front of it to turn it into a link. A moderator or another user with edit privileges can then reinsert the `!` to turn it into an image again.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217834/how-to-create-a-timeline-with-latex

Answer (score 20):

`pgfgantt` and `pst-gantt` are standard in TeX live 2011. As the names suggest the former uses TikZ, the latter PSTricks. `texdoc pgfgantt` and `texdoc pst-gantt` will give the documentation if you have TeX live 2011 installed.

Comment: +1 especially for `texdoc` - how did I not know about this wonderful utility?!

Comment: @ Ant: `texdoc` is the most underestimated utility of the whole TeX-word. I've no idea why the authors of books on LaTeX don't have a frontpage, saying (in friendly, large red type): »Don't panic -- `texdoc` is your friend«.

Comment: Thank you very much!
I will give a better look at texdoc.

Comment: There's also the [gantt package](http://www.martin-kumm.de/tex_gantt_package.php); unfortunately not on CTAN.